# List View creation event

Tags: apex, event, list-view

Is there any way to catch the creation of a new List View? Because I have methods that should run immediately after creating a new List View.

Comment: listview object doesn't support any kind of triggerable event.You can only query existing list view

Comment: U can't catch the creation, but you can do is catch the records making into that list view with the same filter. Just a thought. So with that filters if a record is created, you can assume, your list view is updated, but no not creation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is **no**, there *isn't* a way to capture a list view creation event.

I realize this is a bit of a tough question to answer as you won't find that spelled out explicitly in any of the developer documentation. What I can point you to are two key things:

- [Only DML events are triggerable.†](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_ignoring_operations.htm)

  - *Triggers are invoked for data manipulation language (DML) operations that the Java application server initiates or processes. Therefore, some system bulk operations don't invoke triggers.*
  - †An exception to this are platform events.
- [List views are `ListView` metadata, and as such are managed with the Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_listview.htm) or directly within the browser interface (which is how most users would be managing them).

It is possible to query for `ListView` metadata with SOQL in Apex, however, so depending on your need you could check periodically for new list views and execute some logic.

In doing some digging for this, I also found that with Salesforce Shield or Salesforce Event Monitoring it is possible to capture [List View Events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/sforce_api_objects_listviewevent.htm).